# Microsoft Access Auto Rounding an Average Value from a query

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I'm very new to Microsoft Access and I've run into a bit of a conundrum. I'm building a basic Access database that can help my Dad use past invoices to quote future jobs. I really only have two objects I'm working with. An invoice Table that hold all the costs that we paid for specific metals in 2013 and a Form I'm making that pulls information from that table. In my basic table I have a Currency field called PPLB(Price Per Pound). Now throughout the year we sometimes buy the same metal multiple times and if you know anything about metal, you know that the amount of metal you purchase sometimes affects the price that you pay. So in my Quoting Form I have a Query that looks like this->

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW Avg(MAT_QuickBookInvoices_2013.PPLB) AS [Avg Of PPLB]
FROM MAT_QuickBookInvoices_2013
GROUP BY MAT_QuickBookInvoices_2013.Material, MAT_QuickBookInvoices_2013.[Material Subtype], MAT_QuickBookInvoices_2013.Spec, MAT_QuickBookInvoices_2013.Shape, MAT_QuickBookInvoices_2013.Sizes
HAVING (((MAT_QuickBookInvoices_2013.Material)=[Forms]![MAT_QuoteTable]![Mat_CB]) AND ((MAT_QuickBookInvoices_2013.[Material Subtype])=[forms]![MAT_QuoteTable]![SubType_CB]) AND ((MAT_QuickBookInvoices_2013.Spec)=[forms]![MAT_QuoteTable]![Spec_CB]) AND ((MAT_QuickBookInvoices_2013.Shape)=[forms]![MAT_QuoteTable]![Shape_CB]) AND ((MAT_QuickBookInvoices_2013.Sizes)=[forms]![MAT_QuoteTable]![Size_CB]));
```

I know that's long but what it's doing is grouping the different type of metals into their most common grouping using Combo Boxes in the Quote Form and then finding the average price for that group. So now the problem. When I run the query it pulls up the correct price but when it transfers to the combo box it rounds price to the nearest whole dollar. How can I change or correct this? I've tried changing and formatting the source table as a double instead of currency and this hasn't helped. Any hints at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

On the Property sheet for your comboBox, set the Formay property to Fixed. Then. immediately underneath that, set the number of decimals to 2 or 3 or whatever. That should do it.

Cheers -

Comment: That didn't work. It's still rounding up. Thank-you though for the attempt to help.